# How can I prevent body scrollbar and shifting when twitter bootstrap modal dialog is loaded?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

When I open the twitter bootstrap modal dialog, the backdrop causes a scrollbar and shift the content.

To avoid the scrollbar I use this css:

```
.modal {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But I can not avoid the shift.

regards,
Marko

I am using Bootstrap Version 3

Comment: yes the same problem i also got, you need to make overflow:hidden for the backdrop

Comment: I have tried this, but the problem still exists:

    .modal-backdrop {
        overflow:hidden;
    }

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Marko,

I just had the same problem.  It appears that Bootstrap **3.0.0** adds a class to `<body>`, `modal-open`, when the modal first shows.  This class adds `margin-right: 15px` to the body to account for a scrollbar, which is there on longer pages.  This is great, except for shorter pages when a scrollbar isn't on the body.  In the no scrollbar case, the margin-right causes the body to shift left on modal open.

I was able to solve this by adding some short Javascript and a little CSS:

**CSS:**

```
/* override bootstrap 3 class to remove scrollbar from modal backdrop
   when not necessary */
.modal {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
/* custom class to override .modal-open */
.modal-noscrollbar {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

**JS:**

```
(function($) {

$(document)
    .on( 'hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
        $(document.body).removeClass( 'modal-noscrollbar' );
    })
    .on( 'show.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
        // Bootstrap adds margin-right: 15px to the body to account for a
        // scrollbar, but this causes a "shift" when the document isn't tall
        // enough to need a scrollbar; therefore, we disable the margin-right
        // when it isn't needed.
        if ( $(window).height() >= $(document).height() ) {
            $(document.body).addClass( 'modal-noscrollbar' );
        }
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

These combined permit the margin-right scrollbar fix to work for long pages, yet is disabled for shorter pages (when document height <= window height).  I hope this helps!

---

Bootstrap **3.0.1**+ (tested up to 3.1.1) is a different story.  Try the following:

**CSS:**

```
/* override bootstrap 3 class to remove scrollbar from modal backdrop
   when not necessary */
.modal {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
/* custom class to add space for scrollbar */
.modal-scrollbar {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
(function($) {

$(document)
    .on( 'hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
        $(document.body).removeClass( 'modal-scrollbar' );
    })
    .on( 'show.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
        // Bootstrap's .modal-open class hides any scrollbar on the body,
        // so if there IS a scrollbar on the body at modal open time, then
        // add a right margin to take its place.
        if ( $(window).height() < $(document).height() ) {
            $(document.body).addClass( 'modal-scrollbar' );
        }
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

---

**EDIT**:

In light of Mac eliminating scrollbars from inhabiting window render width, here's a more portable solution (3.0.1+) if you don't mind some feature detection.  Reference: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width

**CSS:**

```
.scrollbar-measure {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
window.jQuery(function() {
  // detect browser scroll bar width
  var scrollDiv = $('<div class="scrollbar-measure"></div>')
        .appendTo(document.body)[0],
      scrollBarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;

  $(document)
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function(evt) {
      // use margin-right 0 for IE8
      $(document.body).css('margin-right', '');
    })
    .on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
      // When modal is shown, scrollbar on body disappears.  In order not
      // to experience a "shifting" effect, replace the scrollbar width
      // with a right-margin on the body.
      if ($(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $(document.body).css('margin-right', scrollBarWidth + 'px');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution. The classes are added to the body element but the scrollbar is already there. 
With the Bootstrap 3.0.2 Version the shift issue is solved.

Comment: Marko, I somehow totally missed your comment.  Thanks for the update, I'll check out the latest Bootstrap.

Comment: It seems the "document height vs window height"-check is reversed? This solution works for me when I replace greater or equal with less or equal

Comment: Interesting... I took another look and determined a difference between 3.0.0 and 3.0.1+ (edited above).  I used a less-than in this case, but also changed the CSS.

Comment: I have no access to the original source code anymore (where the problem exist). But I have tested it and it seems to be work as desired. thx

Comment: I found on my Mac that since OS X did away with scroll bars, this solution was no longer effective.  I added a method that involves sniffing the browser's scroll bar width.

Comment: I'd be careful about using top -9999px.  As I remember there use to be some cases where mobile browsers were trying to draw offscreen pixels and it was really bogging it down.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

For me only the combination of two answers worked.

**css:**

```
body {
    padding-right:0px !important;
    margin-right:0px !important;
}

body.modal-open {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**stylus:**

```
body
  padding-right:0px !important
  margin-right:0px !important
  &.modal-open
    overflow: auto
```

Comment: thank man thank you! This should be accepted answer. I'm using bootstrap 3.3.5

Comment: Here is an even better solution, slight modification...

    body.modal-open {
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

Comment: Works for 3.3.6 as well. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Saved my night! Thx! For 3.3.7.

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
body.modal-open {
overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Mine is easy there it is (CSS Only):

```
body {
padding-right:0px !important;
margin-right:0px !important;
}
```

The fact is the !important is overlapping bootstrap from changing padding and margin with the modal-open class and styles.

Comment: That worked for me. Bummer is that this was supposed to be fixed in 3.0.2 and the issue still exists in 3.3.2.

Comment: Bingo - this is the only solution that worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: body class is applied on which dom element?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with the scroll bar disappearing, and the body shifting to the left when opening a bootstrap modal.

I've found out an easy fix:

```
.modal
{
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}

.modal-open
{
   overflow:auto !important;
   overflow-x:hidden !important;
   padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Good luck to all!

Answer (score 4):

```
body {
    /*prevent modal background jumping*/
    padding-right:0px !important;
    margin-right:0px !important;
}

/*prevent modal background jumping*/
body.modal-open {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is:

- to add to BODY overflow-y: scroll
- and remove 4 functions from bootstrap.js: `checkScrollbar`, `setScrollbar`, `resetScrollbar`, and `measureScrollbar`.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my CSS and seemed to work when adding a 'fixed' overlay to view

```
.modal-open {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple javascript:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
     if ($(document).height() <= $(window).height()) {
         $('body').css('margin-right','0','!important');
      }      
 });
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. this is working fine.

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
      if ($(document).height() <= $(window).height()) {
        $('body').css('margin-right','0','!important');
      }
      else { 
       $('body').removeAttr('style');
      }
    })
    $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The following inclusion to my .css file fixed my centered content page from moving or resizing when the popup modal shows.

I did not need any Javascript, just the css code below. This fixed it for content with or without a vertical or horizontal scrollbar.

```
.modal
{
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}

.modal-open {
    overflow: auto !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    padding-right: 15px !important;
}
```

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7.