# Can scroll with overflow: hidden in Chrome 38

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have website that works with Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.0.
Since Chrome was updated to version 38, the `modal` of Bootstrap, not blocking the scroll when modal is open.

Bootstrap modal using `overflow:hidden` to hide and block the scrollbar. but since the last update, it only hide the scrollbar.

How can I prevent the scrolling while modal is open?

Comment: Duplicate, though Bootstrap may have changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060301/how-to-prevent-background-scrolling-when-bootstrap-3-modal-open-on-mobile-browse, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288546/how-can-i-prevent-body-scrollbar-and-shifting-when-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dialo

Comment: Now Chrome have changed... Bootstrap working in the other browsers

Comment: Can you tell me if your body and html have defined heights at `100%`, that could fix the issue

Comment: Just wanted to say that I can confirm the issue on bootstrap's demo page with Chrome 38. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes. This certainly seems like a bug. I can't imagine Bootstrap would allow these separate functionalities on purpose.

Comment: @MarshallOfSound No, it didn't work

Comment: Seems someone has now reported this as https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14972

Answer (score 2):

Detect the mousewheel and prevent the default action

```
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I prefer CSS solution

Comment: Not wanting to be the bringer of bad news, I don't believe there is one.  `overflow:hidden` in the spec does not require scrolling to be disabled I do not believe.  If you really want to try it out, put a wildcard css rule in `* {overflow:hidden}` and see if you can still scroll

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class to the HTML tag which renders the main content overflow hidden is the best way.

```
html.modal-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Class name to be applied by showModal() and removed by hideModal() functions.

However I've found this can lead to other issues in Chrome where the scrollbar of the modal doesn't seem to focus unless you:

- Right click and inspect an element in the modal scrolling area
- resize the window
- if the page content is more than the height of the window and you have scrolled down the page. Then it scrolls to the top and works as well.

**After experiment I found that**

> transitioned dom elements containing elements with overflow-y Causes a focus issue in Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m

In my case there was a scale transition applied to a popup element,  so I had to remove it.